# Short exact sequences of tensor products

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Can u help me prove that if  $N$ is a free Module and $0 \rightarrow M_1 \rightarrow M_2 \rightarrow M_3 \rightarrow 0 $ is a short exact sequence, with $f_1 : M_1 \rightarrow M_2$ , in this case is gonna be injective,  then $ 0 \rightarrow M_1\bigotimes_AN \rightarrow M_2\bigotimes_AN \rightarrow M_3\bigotimes_AN \rightarrow 0$ is also a short exact sequence. My ony problem is proving that $f_1\bigotimes id$ is injective. I tried using the fact that if N is free then $N\cong \bigoplus_{i \in I} A$ but im not sure if it is the correct way to think about it, Thanks in advance.

Comment: First check $M\otimes_R R\cong M$. This is natural in the sense inducing the map $M_1\otimes_R R\to M_2\otimes_R R$ if you have $M_1\to M_2$. You have to check the natural transformation property of $(-)\otimes_R R\to Id$ between tensor functor and identity functor. Now use isomorphism to deduce tensor product map is injective. For direct sum of free modules, it suffices to note tensor and arbitrary direct sum commute.(This can be exhibited by basis of free module.)

Comment: Im sorry can u be a little more specific , i got a little confused with that part of the functors

Comment: $N=\oplus_i R$. So you want to show $M\otimes_R N=\oplus M^i$. That is all the point. Denote $F=\otimes_R R$ functor. You have to show given $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ inducing $0\to F(A)\to F(B)\to F(C)\to 0$ sequence.(This step is easy.) Now you want to assert $0\to F(A)\to F(B)\to F(C)\to 0$ exact. This is done by comparing $A$ with $F(A)$, $B$ with F(B)$... This part requires naturality which gives you the comparison of effects between identity functor and tensor functor.

Comment: I know funtors preserve isomorphisms , but do they preserve injective functions ?

Comment: Not in general.

Comment: Then i dont get how it is going to help me prove that the first function $f1 \bigotimes id$ is injective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $0\to M\to N$ short exact sequence of modules over ring $A$. Set $F=\oplus_{i\in I}A$ where $I$ is abstract index. For any $A$ module $K$, $K\otimes_AF\cong\oplus_{i\in I} K$. This is a natural morphism. Compare the following sequence with previous sequence.

$0\to M\to N$

$0\to F\otimes M\to F\otimes N$

By naturality of $F\otimes_A(-)\to Id$, one deduces inducing isomorphism vertically between 2 short exact sequences. Note that the diagram is commutative. If upper map is injective, the lower map $F\otimes M\to F\otimes N$ will be injective by commutativity and isomorphism. Take $x\in Ker(F\otimes M\to F\otimes N)$. Now $x$ lifts to an element $x'$ of $M$ by isomorphism and this element has image in $N$ by $M\to N$ map. However $N\cong F\otimes N$ and commutativity of diagram forces the image in $N$ being $0$. Hence  by $M\to N$ injective $x'=0$.

Comment: Alright i think i understand it , thanks. Im just having some troubles skiping from the tensor product of the modules to the $\bigoplus M $ and $\bigoplus N$, just one question how do i know that the diagram is commutative?

Comment: @PedroSantos The map $M\otimes F\to\oplus M$ can be concretely given. Furthermore, $M\otimes F$ is nothing more than $M\otimes A$ itself. If you understand $F=A$ case, then you will understand $F=\oplus A$ case by extending basis. For $F=A$ case, it should be trivial to see as you have canonical multiplication map $M\times A\to M$ which clearly descends to isomorphism on $M\otimes_A A\to M$.

Comment: @PedroSantos Pick a basis of $F$ and consider $m\otimes e_i$ with $e_i$ basis of $F$. Now you identify $m\otimes e_i=m e_i$ where $e_i$ is the $i-$th component of $\oplus M$.